# MongoDB ACID transactions vs RDMBS - Performance

Tags: mongodb, acid

I am looking for some comparison between Mongo DB with ACID support vs RDBMS. I would like to see if Mongo DB with ACID can be a replacement for RDBMS for most of the scenarios. With earlier Mongo DB versions, the biggest gap between Mongo DB and RDBMS was support of transactions. A performance comparison (with transactions) would be a great help

https://www.mongodb.com/basics/acid-transactions

[https://scalegrid.io/blog/mongodb-acid/#:~:text=Traditional%20Relational%20Database%20Management%20Systems,of%20integrity%2C%20their%20architectures%20differ](https://scalegrid.io/blog/mongodb-acid/#:%7E:text=Traditional%20Relational%20Database%20Management%20Systems,of%20integrity%2C%20their%20architectures%20differ).

https://www.mongodb.com/collateral/mongodb-multi-document-acid-transactions

Also as per the below article, *'MongoDB is not suited for complex transactional applications'.*

The above is a generic statement and could be more useful with some scenarios

https://www.astera.com/type/blog/mongodb-vs-sql-server/